# Where is the root path from the perspective of an Android app?

Tags: android, filepath

The page on [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) shows an example usage of its library

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File("/images/oprah_bees.gif")).into(imageView2);
```

I suppose `images` is not actually in the root folder of the device, maybe the assets folder of the app?

Comment: I'm not quite sure on this either. Being that Android is based on the linux kernel, I would assume that call to be accessing images in root.  You can however always try creating a `File` in the manner they show and then Log the file.getAbsolutePath() to find where the file was opened.

Comment: You get files from the assests folder using getResources() and a R.drawable.  Good Luck @Maarten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose images is not actually in the root folder of the device

According to that `File` object, that is exactly where it is. This is... unrealistic.

Comment: Huh, fancy that. By chance, do you also know where `File("images/oprah_bees.gif")` would point to? I can't find docs on this.

Comment: @Maarten: No clue. Generally, you want to use a `File` constructor that takes another `File` as the root directory, passing in a known good value (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).